# Image attribute in Product Flat Catalog

Tags: magento-1.8, image, flat-catalog

I have a Magento 1.8 CE and I figured out that when using "Product Flat Catalog", the attribute "image" is not collected. 
How can i add that attribute to "Product Flat Catalog" 
It is not possible to set "Use for Listing" from Manage Attributes.

Any other way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution that I found is most clean and uses Magento's XML-style abstractions to add the image column to the `catalog_product_flat_1` table:
try this code:-
In config.xml:

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <product>
            <collection>
                <attributes>
                    <image />
               </attributes>
            </collection>
        </product>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Then reindex your flat catalog tables *(Admin > Index Management > Select All + Reindex)* and clear all Magento caches.

Comment: Shall I add that code in app/etc/config.xml?

Comment: yes add the code frinds

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by adding `image` attribute at `frontend/product/collection/attributes` node at config.xml

```
<frontend>
    <product>
        <collection>
            <attributes>
                  <image/>
            </attributes>
        </collection>
    </product>
</frontend>
```

### Explanation:

**Let explain:**

First look at class [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer`](https://github.com/engineyard/magento-ce-1.9/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php) .

and a function name `getAttributeCodes()` which responsible  for   columns creation at `catalog product flat`.

Magento is first take  the attributse from `global/catalog/product/flat/attribute_nodes`  using

**Mage::getConfig() ->getNode(self::XML_NODE_ATTRIBUTE_NODES)
                ->children();**

from [`config.xml`](https://github.com/engineyard/magento-ce-1.9/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml) at `app/code/core/Mage_Catalog/etc/`

```
<flat>
    <max_index_count>64</max_index_count>
    <attribute_nodes>
        <product_collection>frontend/product/collection/attributes</product_collection>
    </attribute_nodes>
    <add_filterable_attributes>0</add_filterable_attributes>
    <add_child_data>0</add_child_data>
    <flag>
        <model>catalog/product_flat_flag</model>
    </flag>
</flat>
```

Which  internally call **config node**: `frontend/product/collection/attributes`.

If we define an attribute here then this attribute will automatically  added as columns in `flat table`.

```
<frontend>
    <product>
        <collection>
            <attributes>
                  <attribute_Code/>
            </attributes>
        </collection>
    </product>
</frontend>
```

Then need to product flat index form index management.