# call two images in list.phtml in magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.9.2.1

`onmouseout` I want to display the second image of the product.

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image'); ?>"  onmouseover="this.src = '<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image'); ?>';" 
                 onmouseout="this.src = '<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image'); ?>';" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
</a>
```

i used this code but it will display two images consectively and i am unable to seperate them for onmouseover and onmouseout.

```
<?php 
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());

foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
    echo var_export($image->getUrl());
} 
 ?>
```

Comment: what you mean by  second. are taking about second image of gallery?Please clarify  everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this with **id**

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image'); ?>" id="imageid"  onmouseover="document.getElementById('imageid').src = '<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image'); ?>';" 
                 onmouseout="document.getElementById('imageid').src = '<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image'); ?>';" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```

for separate the images

```
<?php 
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
$img=array();
foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
    $img[]=$image->getUrl();
} 
?>
```

simple separate with `$img[0]` for first and `$img[1]` for second

Comment: not working.. and image is not called. only one images display which is in the source.

Comment: because you are using same image for all. update answer

Answer (score 2):

In edition of [@Qaisar answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/107734/4564)

If you enable flat table then `<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image'); ?>` does not give you image url  because of *Base image(attribute code image)* does not included at flat table.

In order to image  get image field value,you need to enable image at flat table.
See   How to add  [Image attribute in Product Flat Catalog](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72910/image-attribute-in-product-flat-catalog/72912#72912)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"
   title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"
   class="product-image">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(135); ?>"
         width="135"
         height="135"
         class="product-image-first"
         alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"
        />
    <?php
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $_product */
$_product->load('media_gallery');
$collection = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages();
foreach ($collection as $_image):
    if ($_image->getPosition() != 2) {
        continue;
    }
    ?>
    <img
        src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $_image->getFile())->resize(135); ?>"
        width="135"
        height="135"
        class="product-image-second"
        alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_image->getLabel()) ?>"
        style="display: none;"
        />
    <?php
endforeach;
?>
```

Add script at bottom of page:

```
    var productImagesFirst = document.querySelectorAll('.product-image');
    for (var key in productImagesFirst) {
        if (productImagesFirst.hasOwnProperty(key) && productImagesFirst[key] instanceof Element) {
            var productImage = productImagesFirst[key];
            console.log(productImage);
            productImage.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e){
                var first = e.target.querySelector('.product-image-first');
                var second = e.target.querySelector('.product-image-second');
                if (second) {
                    first.hide();
                    second.show();
                }
            });
            productImage.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e){
                var first = e.target.querySelector('.product-image-first');
                var second = e.target.querySelector('.product-image-second');
                if (second) {
                    first.show();
                    second.hide();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```